# How to check stream.data to read for certain users twitterapi

Tags: node.js, twitter

So I've coded a twitter bot to respond to one particular person with one particular message assuming it's an original tweet

The code is as follows: (ids hidden)

```
import { TwitterApi } from 'twitter-api-v2';
import { TwitterV2IncludesHelper } from 'twitter-api-v2';

var xdsds = ""
const client = new TwitterApi({
  appKey: 'censored',
  appSecret: 'censored',
  accessToken: 'censored',
  accessSecret: 'censored',
});

async function loop(){
  const stream = await client.v2.userTimeline('censored',{
    'tweet.fields': ['referenced_tweets', 'author_id'],
    expansions: ['referenced_tweets.id', 'author_id'],
  });

  for await (const tweet of stream) {
    if(stream.data.author_id == 'censored'){
      console.log('you found a yeeyeeass mayank tweet')
    }
    xdsds = stream.data;
    console.log(xdsds)
  }

}

loop();
```

My primary issue now, is that I cannot sort through things based on author id as it doesn't work. Any ideas? And how can I stop it from responding to the same tweet twice/replying to replies rather then original tweets

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate, you want to reply to any tweet posted by a particular user, which is not a reply, nor retweet. For the sake of my answer I assume that `'censored'` value in `client.v2.userTimeline` call and `stream.data.author_id` comparison is the same.

Your condition doesn't check the value of the `author_id` for a tweet, you are accessing `stream.data.author_id`, but you should be checking: `tweet.author_id == 'censored'`.

However, there might be a better solution. Checking the [user timeline API docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets), there is `exclude` parameter. If you exclude both `retweets` and `replies`, you don't need to check the `author_id` altogether *and* you won't receive any replies:

```js
const stream = await client.v2.userTimeline('censored', {
  exclude: 'retweets,replies'
});
```

To avoid responding to the same tweet twice, use either `since_id`, or `start_time` parameters to receive only tweets which were posted since your last request. You can persist the value to a disk or database so it survives between script runs.

For example (untested):

```js
let lastTweetSince = undefined;

async function loop(){
  const stream = await client.v2.userTimeline('censored',{
    exclude: 'retweets,replies',
    since_id: lastTweetSince,
  });

  // Get the ID of the newest tweet in the response
  lastTweetSince = stream.tweets[0].id;
  
  // ...
}
```

(See [paginator docs](https://github.com/PLhery/node-twitter-api-v2/blob/master/doc/paginators.md))